# What is the bracha for candied raw Etrog?

Tags: blessing

On Sunday, I saw a box of candied Etrog in my local store. I'm assuming that they made this available in honor of Tu B'Shevat. The etrog pieces are clearly recognizable other than the coating of loads of sugar on the outside. Assume that the etrog pieces are raw, not cooked, for purposes of making this concoction.

Is the bracha *ha'etz* or *shehakol*? I'm assuming it's *shehakol* based on the idea that if one eats a fruit or vegetable (e.g. raw potatoes) that is normally not eaten raw in his community, [one says *shehakol*](http://www.berachot.org/halacha/19_changing.html) In the U.S., raw etrog is not eaten, commonly. Does the sugar coating change the bracha status?

Comment: basically identical http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64432/759

Answer (score 4):

In the discussion we need to examine three possibilities: Shehakkol,  Adama and  Haets.

I assume that the Etrog is eaten candied only.

Candied orange and lemon peels are addressed in poskim around   Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim siman 202,  sayf 6. e. g.  [Magen Avraham sk 17](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%95) .  The Magen Avraham addresses a kind of orange which is not edible easily without sugar. He says that the peel needs Haets because he remains over the fruit all time in the tree and has dine Orla. The fruit also needs to be candied for a good consumption. This is lechaora similar to the Etrog addressed in OP.

Answer: Bore Peri Haets.

Comment: Thanks. I really was not expecting this type of answer, as I was unaware of this sort of discussion! I have to view this, myself. If possible, link one or more items, above.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to Q8 [here](http://www.berachot.org/Q+A/index.html#crispix). I am citing just the relevant part:

> (As a side note, if one put sugar or something similar on the lemon,
>   it would then qualify for Ha'etz.)

Etrog is very similar to lemon. So, I've concluded that putting sugar on the etrog would follow the same criterion.

Comment: +1 but i can't believe you passed up the opportunity to mention the criterion for the citron.

Comment: @user6591 OK, what did I miss?

Comment: Just the bad pun. Nothing major.